# Accessing struct member through unique_ptr gives segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

This is how I set pointer to struct. At runtime segmentation fault is thrown at second line. LoadedPDFInfo is struct in Canvas namespace

```
struct std::unique_ptr<Canvas::LoadedPDFInfo> pdfInfo;
pdfInfo->handle = ++currentPDFHandle;
pdfInfo->totalPageNum = FPDF_GetPageCount(doc);
```

Comment: C++ is not C is not C++!

Comment: @Olaf do you have a answer to it?

Comment: How would I? The crystal ball is misty and I'm no clairvoyant. See [ask].

Comment: @Olaf what is so "misty" in it? let me know so that i can make it less "misty"

Comment: @chema989: `std::unique_ptr` is only available in C++11 and later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `std::unique_ptr` is a `class` not a `struct`, so get rid of the `struct` prefix on the `pdfInfo` variable declaration.  You were probably thinking of this instead:

```
std::unique_ptr<struct Canvas::LoadedPDFInfo> pdfInfo;
```

But even when declaring variables (or type-casting) using actual `struct` types, you still do not need the `struct` prefix.  C needs that, C++ does not.

Second, your segfault is happening because you have merely declared the `pdfInfo` variable, but it is not actually pointing at a valid `LoadedPDFInfo` object, so using the `->` operator is not a valid operation.  Just like a regular pointer, `std::unique_ptr` (and `std::auto_ptr`, and `std::shared_ptr`) have to *point at something* in order to access *that something's* members.  For example:

```
std::unique_ptr<Canvas::LoadedPDFInfo> pdfInfo(new Canvas::LoadedPDFInfo);
```

Comment: Another option is `auto pdfInfo = std::make_unique<Canvas::LoadedPDFInfo>();`, which reduces code duplication in mentioning the type name twice

Comment: `std::make_unique()` was added in C++14, which is not widely used yet. You can write an equivalent function in C++11, though. Besides, the real purpose of `std::make_unique()` is more for better memory management, not better code readability. Also, calling the `std::unique_ptr` constructor directly does have one benefit - you can decide where the object pointer comes from, you don't have to call `new` directly in the constructor, eg: `std::unique_ptr<Canvas::LoadedPDFInfo> pdfInfo( GetLoadedPDFInfoPointer() );`, though in that case you probably should be using `std::shared_ptr` instead.

Comment: `make_unique` doesn't have better memory management than `new`.  It has better exception safety in cases where you have multiple allocations without a sequence point.